# Java Lang No Class Error: InlineContentView

Tags: java, android-studio

I am working with the custom keyboard where am having an issue with the InlineContentView in Android Studio that says:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/widget/inline/InlineContentView;
> at com.android.bodo.InlineContentClipView.clipDescendantInlineContentViews(InlineContentClipView.java:143)
> at com.android.bodo.InlineContentClipView.clipDescendantInlineContentViews(InlineContentClipView.java:135)
> at com.android.bodo.InlineContentClipView.$r8$lambda$2T6oFHLhHlgispfW-UyrqrxrHlY(Unknown Source:0)
> at com.android.bodo.InlineContentClipView$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onDraw(Unknown Source:2)

Any links and information?

it seems like it is deprecated i looked into newer version to solve but i need some suggestions

Comment: What version of Android are you targeting?  InlineContentView was only introduced in API level 30.

Comment: Yea ... it hasn't been deprecated.

Comment: i am building on api 29. does that mean InlineContentView cannot be used on API29?